# Is it possible to hybrid boot Debian 11?

Tags: arch-linux

I want to make a hybrid boot in Debian so that it runs in both uefi and bios, is it possible to do this and how?

Answer (score 1):

**Technically** yes, basically in the same way as you do it with Arch or any other distribution. Neither the installed Linux kernel nor the userspace tools are specific to either boot mode, i.e. the same `/vmlinuz` can be used for both, so all you need is to install the correct bootloaders for both firmware modes.

The main problem is that if you're using GRUB2, you'll find that the Debian package containing GRUB modules for BIOS is defined to conflict with the one that ships modules for UEFI systems, i.e. dpkg will not allow you to have both installed.

To avoid this packaging annoyance, you'll need to use two *different* bootloaders:

- One option is to use Syslinux for BIOS boot, while keeping GRUB2 for UEFI.

  Syslinux has special `gptmbr.bin` BIOS MBR bootcode that supports looking for GPT partitions having the 'Legacy Boot' flag in the same way as it would normally look for MBR partitions having the 'Active' flag – the existing EFI System Partition can be marked as 'Legacy Boot' and the FAT32-compatible variant of Syslinux installed to its VBR.

  Don't forget to create a Syslinux menu item that'll boot Debian.
- The other option is to install GRUB2 for BIOS, then use systemd-boot for UEFI.

  systemd-boot seems to be available in bullseye-backports, and in any case it's a self-contained .efi file that could be copied from Arch or another distribution.

  Again, you'll need to manually create a systemd-boot entries/*.conf file that will boot Debian.

The second problem is that APT's post-upgrade scripts might not necessarily update *both* bootloader configurations whenever a new kernel version is installed, but that can be dealt with separately.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to revert BIOS between each boot. An error (easy to do) could cause some significant damage.

Regular operating systems cannot change BIOS when starting or running.

So to answer your question (hybrid boot in Debian) with a short answer:

**No, not practical.**

If you need to do what you are trying to do, use a Virtual Machine. Works great.